# Teradata - Populating columns based on values

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to populate table based on row value.

Source

```
Cust_num    Rule    Amt Cnt
1   CHQ 40  2
1   ONL 20  4
2   CHQ 11  1
```

Target

```
Cust_Num    CHQ_AMT  CHQ_CNT   ONL_AMT  ONL_CNT
1            40        2         20       4
2            11        1          0       0
```

Say for first customer number 1, it is under two rules. So I am populating values for those. For cust num 2, on values for ONL. So I am populating 0s. Can you assist me how to achieve this in Teradata 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of rules is known you can use MAX/CASE:

```
select Cust_num
   ,max(case when Rule = 'CHQ' then Amt else 0 end) as CHQ_AMT
   ,max(case when Rule = 'CHQ' then Cnt else 0 end) as CHQ_CNT
   ,max(case when Rule = 'ONL' then Amt else 0 end) as ONL_AMT
   ,max(case when Rule = 'ONL' then Cnt else 0 end) as ONL_CNT
from tab
group by 1
```

If there might be multiple rows per cust_num/rule you can switch to `SUM` instead of `MAX`.

Comment: in the same scenario, if my source has 6 months of data, and my target has CHQ_M1_AMT,CHQ_M2_AMT,CHQ_M3_AMT......CHQ_M6_AMT.... How can this query be modified to get the result. Say my M1 column will have current month data, M2 has Current month -1 data..... M6 has curr month - 5 data.. My souce has 6 months of data

Comment: @Madhan: e.g. to get the previous month's data: `SUM(CASE WHEN datecol BETWEEN TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE,-1), 'MON') AND LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE,-1)) THEN Amt ELSE 0 END)`